# Why is it hard to make black clothes?

Tags: visible-light

I've noticed that we have so-called 'black' clothes everywhere, I haven't seen so far any piece of clothes that would be **really** black, it's always some kind of lighter black.

For instance, if you take a 'black' shirt then put some water on it, the stain will look even darker.

Why is it so hard to make (nearly) totally black clothes?

Comment: What material do you know that absorbes absolutely all visible light, reflecting nothing at all. "Nothing" is a rather small value.  The same issue goes for white too.  Some material would have to reflect all visible light.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Well, I don't really know how good we are at creating materials that absorb a lot of light and can be used in clothes :) which is why I made this question. I thought those kind of clothes might exist for specific branches (military, ...)

Comment: I posted an answer to a question very similar to this on another site recently.  It's not really Physics.SE quality but you might find it interesting: http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=323898#p323898 (EDIT: I just realized you can't see the images in the post.  I'll think about how to clean the post up and make it an answer here.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a nontrivial problem in materials science.   People have done a lot of work both with different materials and different surface structures to create "ultra-black" absorbing structures for use in optical systems.
A big part of the problem is the statistical nature of photon absorption.  There's only a certain percent (<100) chance of absorbing a given photon with a given material.  Changing the macro structure to force a large number of reflections increases the net probability of absorption.

Oddly enough,  the military does not want perfect absorption: it's just as easy to detect a "hole" in the environment as a "beacon."  Camouflage is designed, roughly, to have a reflective parameter indistinguishable from the intended local environment.

Comment: Carl this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @BrandonEnright ok, what do you interpret the question as?

Comment: I think I interpreted the question the same as you.  But your answer basically says it's non-trivial and then you provide a bit about photon absorption stats and then finish with a only partially related anecdote.  You didn't mention anything about reflectivity or how not all frequencies are easy to absorb equally.